# Display image or video depending on Content-Type/ mime-type in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am using expo-image-picker to upload the images and videos. However, I had a problem while displaying the image and the videos from the database. How can I display them by using `mime-type` condition or `media-type` condition?
Please let me know if anyone knows about it.

```
  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.android) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      status = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      // allowsEditing: true,
      // aspect: [9, 16],
      quality: 1.0,
      allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
      this.setState({ type: result.type });
    }
  };





  _openCamera = async () => {
    // this._toggleModal(false);
    let permission = await this._cameraPermission()
    if (permission) {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [9, 16],
        quality: 1.0,
        // base64: false,
      })
      console.log(result);
      // this._uploadPhoto(result)
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.setState({ image: result.uri });
        this.setState({ type: result.type });
      }
    } else {
      this.refs.popupComponent.showPopupMessage("Need Permission", "Close");
      console.log("Need Permission")
    }
  }

  _cameraPermission = async () => {
    status = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    // const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    let statusCamera = status.status;
    console.log("statusCameraRoll: ", statusCamera);
    if (statusCamera !== "granted") {
      console.log("Requesting Notification Permissions");
      status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      statusCamera = status.status;
      if (statusCamera != '"granted"')
        return false
      else {
        let status_new = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        let statusCameraRoll = status_new.status;
        if (statusCameraRoll !== "granted") {
          status_new = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
          statusCameraRoll = status_new.status
          if (statusCameraRoll !== "granted")
            return false
          else
            return true
        }
        else
          return true
      }
    }
    else {
      let status_new = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      let statusCameraRoll = status_new.status;
      if (statusCameraRoll !== "granted") {
        status_new = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        statusCameraRoll = status_new.status
        if (statusCameraRoll !== "granted")
          return false
        else
          return true
      }
      else
        return true
    }

  }

  _videoHandler = async () => {
    // this._toggleModal(false);
    let permission = await this._galleryPermission()
    setTimeout
    if (permission) {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
        // allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [9, 16],
        quality: 1.0,
        // allowsMultipleSelection: true,
        // base64: false,
      });
      console.log(result);
      // this._uploadPhoto(result)
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.setState({ video: result.uri });
        this.setState({ type: result.type });
      }
    } else {
      this.refs.popupComponent.showPopupMessage("Need Permission", "Close");
      console.log("Need Permission")
    }
  };

  _galleryPermission = async () => {
    status = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    // const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    let statusCameraRoll = status.status;
    console.log("statusCameraRoll: ", statusCameraRoll);
    if (statusCameraRoll !== "granted") {
      console.log("Requesting Notification Permissions");
      status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      statusCameraRoll = status.status;
      if (statusCameraRoll != '"granted"')
        return false
      else
        return true
    }
    else
      return true
  }



<View style="{styles.mediaComponent}">
        <Image style={styles.imageView} source={{ uri: this.state.image }} />
        <View>
          <Video
            source={{ uri: this.state.video }}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: 300 }}
            resizeMode="cover"
            shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
            isMuted={this.state.mute}
          />
          <View style="{styles.controlBar}">
            <MaterialIcons
              name={this.state.mute ? "volume-mute" : "volume-up"}
              size={45}
              color="white"
              onPress={this.handleVolume}
            />{" "}
            <MaterialIcons
              name={this.state.shouldPlay ? "pause" : "play-arrow"}
              size={45}
              color="white"
              onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause}
            />
          </View>
         </View>
</View>
```

When we select the files from the gallery we will get mediatype by using
`this.setState({ type: result.type });`, 
By using the type first we need to show the preview of the image or video after that we can store the data in database.

In the same way by using same condition we need to show the data from database like Instagram . 
Once go through the code and tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Sivasankar chimata,

You can **if-check** for upcoming mimeType with ES6's new `endsWith` method. After you get the which type of data you have, you can simply put your business logic for both Image or Video.

Here is a simple code example:

```js
checkIfImage = () => {
 const { mimeType } = this.state;
 if (mimeType.endsWith(".png") || mimeType.endsWith(".jpg")) return true;
 return false;
};
```

**EDIT:**

if-check condition in JSX Elements:

```js
<View>{ this.checkIfImage() ? <Image /> : <Video /> }</View>
```

You can do something like this or even handle it into the another function and return it. With JSX everything is possible :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply can please write the full code , like where to use it and how to use it .

Comment: Hello sir @kuray tell me how can i use if-check in reactive native <view> element

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working according to my requirement  by using conditions
`{this.state.type ===''? <View />:<View />}`

```
{this.state.type === 'image' ?
              <Image style={styles.imageView} source={{ uri: this.state.image }} />
              : null}

            {this.state.type === 'video' ?
              < View >
                <Video
                  source={{ uri: this.state.video }}
                  style={{ width: '100%', height: 300 }}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
                  isMuted={this.state.mute}
                />
                <View style={styles.controlBar}>
                  <MaterialIcons
                    name={this.state.mute ? "volume-mute" : "volume-up"}
                    size={45}
                    color="white"
                    onPress={this.handleVolume}
                  />
                  <MaterialIcons
                    name={this.state.shouldPlay ? "pause" : "play-arrow"}
                    size={45}
                    color="white"
                    onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
              : null}
```

Comment: I've also edited my answer with an example. Do you need anything else?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response and time @Kuray-FreakyCoder- .